# Display count or report of Application that are not available on both tables

Tags: sql, oracle

Display count or report of Application that are not available on both tables
(Services, Services_Done)

**Note**:
Services = Application_no (**number**)
Services_Done = Application_no (**Varchar2**)

```
SELECT Count(Application_no)
FROM services
WHERE Application_cat = 60
and To_char(Delivery_date,'yyyy') between 2006 and 2016
and Service_status = 210

SELECT services.application_no
FROM services
WHERE Application_status = 15
and To_char(Directors_Dependency_Date,'yyyy') between 2006 and 2016
MINUS
SELECT services.application_no
FROM services
JOIN services_contract ON services.application_no=services_contract.application_no
```

Result:

If application avaible in services but not services_done - include it
if Application_no in both table = exclude it

Comment: Your first and last statement contradict each other. Also for code, use code format of stack overflow for a better view.

Comment: I don't understand. You want to select the services that are done? Or the services that are not done? Or what else? What are the tables' unique keys? Is `application_no` the service ID? Or something else entirely? It will help, if you show sample data and its expected result.

Comment: fixed thats not done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF I understand correctly, you can use `NOT EXISTS` clause. Check the example below

```
SELECT Count(Application_no) FROM services s
WHERE Application_cat = 60
and To_char(Delivery_date,'yyyy') between 2006 and 2016
and Service_status = 210
and not exists
(
   select 1 from services_done t2 where t2.cond = s.cond
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `Application` has the same ID in `Services` and `Services_Done`, you can do a `LEFT JOIN` like that :

```
SELECT Count(S.App)
FROM Services as S
LEFT JOIN Services_Done as SD
ON S.App = SD.App
WHERE SD.App is not null;
```

If the condition `WHERE` is met, it means that a link between `Services` and `Services_Done` was found for your object `Application`.